# XAMPP Mysql shutdown unexpevtedly

Tags: mysql, shutdown, xampp, mysqldump, innodb

Please, my MySQL is damaged after my PC suddenly shutdown.

```
18:05:24 [mysql] Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
18:05:24 [mysql] This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
18:05:24 [mysql] improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
18:05:24 [mysql] Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
18:05:24 [mysql] the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
18:05:24 [mysql] If you need more help, copy and post this
18:05:24 [mysql] entire log window on the forums
```

the error log

```
2019-10-14 17:50:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-10-14 17:50:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-10-14 17:50:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-10-14 17:50:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-10-14 17:50:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-10-14 17:50:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-10-14 17:50:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-10-14 17:50:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-10-14 17:50:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-10-14 17:50:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-10-14 17:50:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-10-14 17:50:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-10-14 17:50:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.6 started; log sequence number 113890; transaction id 9
2019-10-14 17:50:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-10-14 17:50:33 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-10-14 17:50:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 191014 17:50:33
2019-10-14 17:50:33 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2019-10-14 18:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-10-14 18:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-10-14 18:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-10-14 18:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-10-14 18:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-10-14 18:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-10-14 18:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-10-14 18:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-10-14 18:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-10-14 18:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-10-14 18:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-10-14 18:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-10-14 18:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.6 started; log sequence number 113899; transaction id 9
2019-10-14 18:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-10-14 18:05:13 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-10-14 18:05:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 191014 18:05:13
2019-10-14 18:05:13 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

and every time I try to connect to mysql, it will die suddenly, pls help me :"(

Comment: Something might have gone wrong with the `C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1` File. It is truncating it twice to the Size of 12 Mega-Bytes. Maybe the File System has gotten corrupted. I would run a "`ChkDsk.Exe /F C:`" Check of the Disk from the Command-Line PreProcessor or another Disk Doctor Static Software Application.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try with removing the **PID** that **mysql** is running.
You can find the **PID** that **mysql** is running using **Netstat** that is there in the control panel.

If you are running xampp on windows then you have to open command prompt in **administration mood** to run the following command inorder to remove the **PID**.

```
taskkill /PID {PID number}
```

Else if you are running on linux,

```
kill -{SIGNAL} {PID number}
```

ex: kill -9 3827

```
 Signal Name      Single Value        Effect

  SIGHUP            1                 Hangup
  SIGINT            2                 Interrupt from keyboard
  SIGKILL           9                 Kill signal
  SIGTERM           15                Termination signal
  SIGSTOP        17, 19, 23           Stop the process
```

This is the list of signals that are there.

After removing just restart the **mysql** service.

Hope this will help you.